# True/false : $\mathbb{Q}$ is connected with respect to the co - countable topology

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Is $\mathbb{Q}$ is  connected  with respect to the  co - countable topology ?

My attempt  :Suppose A and B are disjoint nonempty open sets such that $\mathbb{Q}=A\cup B$, then both A and B are countable.  But $B \subset A^c$ and $A^c$ is ucountable which is a contradiction.  So $\mathbb{Q}$ is connected.

Is  its  true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathbb Q$ is countable, the cocountable topology in $\mathbb Q$ is the discrete topology. And no discrete space with more than one point is connected.

Comment: that mean $\mathbb{Q}$ is not connected  ?

Comment: It means that $\mathbb Q$, endowed with the cocountable topology, is not connected.

Comment: oks  thanks u sir

Comment: sir one more  confusion  why it will be discrete topology for $\mathbb{Q}$ but  not in $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Because in $\mathbb R$, endowed with the cocountable topology, $[0,\infty)$ is not open. Therefore, in $\mathbb R$ the cocountable topology and the discrete topology are distinct. But in $\mathbb Q$, endowed with the cocountable topology, every subset is open and therefore, in $\mathbb Q$, the cocountable topology and the discrete topology are the same topologies.

Comment: got its  sir   thanks u

Comment: I'm glad I could help.